Why do I get very slow internet speed in my phone but in the other devices the Internet speed is normal.(Did 3 speed test at the same time)
Wi-Fi Not Working on Phone but Working on Other Devices
After updating to the new software 6 days ago, I can't use my wifi internet with full efficiency to my phone. My phone is vivo Y35 Android
It shows that the wifi is connected but I'm not able to get any internet. When I tested the wifi speed on my phone, it says its below 0.5 mbps. This is been happening from 6 days now. And the same wifi is working just fine on other devices(Laptop and other other phone) giving around 30-40 mbps.
I've already tried forgetting the network and reconnecting it , restarting my Wi-Fi,  restarting my phone, resetting the network connections .

Try different Wifis (e.g. public Wifis). If the performance is also bad try a factory reset. If that doesn't help it may be a hardware problem.
